# How can I find out who owns a block of IPs?

Tags: attacks, logging

I'm currently going through the logs on my apache install for potential intrustions, and I'm finding a lot of hits for SQL injections and exploit testing, from 173.212.195.* . I'm now trying to find out how I could find who owns the block of IPs which these IPs sit in?

I've looked at [Wikipedia's list of assigned Class A netblocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks), but I can only seem to find lists for non-regional and non-country lists. Can anyone tell me where I could find these lists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That would be a [WHOIS lookup](http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/)

Answer (score 0):

The whois search for the IP at [Whoisxy.com](http://www.whoisxy.com/) will provide the NetRange, CIDR, OriginAS and many more details along with the Abuse Email-id which will help in solving this problem.